# Uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rails::Database (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

When I try to run cucumber in my console i receive this error..

`Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.

uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rails::Database (NameError)
/path_to/app_name/features/support/env.rb:57:in`'`

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

gem 'pg'

gem 'devise'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem "less-rails"
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'slim'

# Omniauth gems
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

# Images
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2'
gem 'carrierwave'

# feed
gem 'feedzirra'

#cron
gem 'whenever', :require => false

#search
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'

#ActiveAdmin
gem 'activeadmin'

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem "email_spec"
  gem "pickle"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "thin"
  gem "capistrano"
end
```

I don't know what is happening, I only guess that could be some gem conflict, but I don't really know.

I've found other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438364/uninitialized-constant-cucumberrailsdatabase-nameerror-cucumber-mongoid) but It's still failing..
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had an old release of the cucumber-rails gem, so I had to put

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> latest_version', :require => false
```

And run:

```
bundle update
```

And all started to work!