# How to configure Cucumber and Capybara to use the Rack::Test driver?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am a newbie to Capybara.

Here is my configuration within file env.rb

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  #config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.default_driver = :rack_test
  config.app_host = 'point to my localhost port 3000'
```

`end`

Everything runs just fine if I set default_driver to :selenium. But I need to set the driver to :rack_test, so that when running cucumber command, it will not open the web browser.

Many thanks,

P/S If you are an expert, please show me the learning path, I'm not expecting someone showing them selves.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to test against a test server controlled by capybara (which is the normal way to do it), rather than testing against your dev instance (the one at localhost:3000) or a staging server or something.

First, configure capybara to run your Rails app. The usual way to do this is to add the cucumber-rails gem to your Gemfile and `require 'cucumber/rails'` in your env.rb. You can also [set up capybara to run Rails (or any Rack app) manually](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber).

Having done that, capybara will do what you want (use the Rack::Test driver) by default. Remove the configuration that you showed from your env.rb and Cucumber/capybara will work the way you want.

If you also want some scenarios to use Javascript, tag those scenarios with @javascript and add

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

to your env.rb. Capybara will continue to use its Rack::Test driver for scenarios without the tag, and will use its Selenium driver for scenarios with the tag.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your feedback. From your instruction, I devise some scenarios as following:

Scenario 1> remove everything from file env.rb (i.e env.rb is empty file - I think this is a wrong way to do configuration but I give it a try), then run command "cucumber", I got this error message "uninitialized constant Rack (NameError)"

Comment: Scenario 2> I remove all other configuration, but I still keep 2 lines of config (i.e: "require 'capybara/cucumber'", and "require 'rspec/expectations'", then run command "cucumber" again, I got this error message "rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given (ArgumentError)"

Comment: Scenario 3> The same as Scenario 2 above, plus 1 more line of configuration, which is "Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium", then I run command "cucumber" again, the error message is "rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given (ArgumentError)"

Comment: I didn't mean empty your env.rb, I meant remove only the configuration *that you showed*. Don't know why that would lead to your error, however.

Comment: Hi Dave, I had tried what you suggest in "Scenario 3" above and it failed.

Comment: Might be that you need to use cucumber-rails and `require 'cucumber-rails'`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I've just tested with your new update. So that, the new configuration of env.rb contains 3 lines: require 'capybara/cucumber', require 'rspec/expectations', require 'cucumber-rails' ; Then I run command cucumber , I got error: "cannot load such file -- cucumber-rails (LoadError)"; I had already put "gem 'cucumber-rails'" within Gemfile a long time ago.

Comment: From this link: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber, I think I should add "Capybara.app = MyRackApp", but I don't know which string I should replace to "MyRackApp". I tried with the name of application module within file config/application.rb and also failed. If you have any other thought , please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `require 'cucumber/rails'`, not `require 'cucumber-rails'`. Read the Capybara docs carefully; you do not need to set `Capybara.app` if you use the cucumber-rails gem.

Comment: I have another issue now, although I had put "Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium", but the test still failed to checking a value within dropdown. i.e "select 'Meat', :from => 'Sub category'" . This test was success as per configuration that I provided within the question.

Comment: I was in another deadline task. Thank you for keep up with this issue. Dave, I did not use @javascript anywhere within the testing code.

Comment: Tag scenarios that should use Selenium with @javascript (as the answer says).

Comment: Within file "first_test.feature", I put "@javascript" right above line "Scenario: Open new product page" ... and I got this error: uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rails::Database::Strategy::DatabaseCleaner (NameError)

Comment: I think may be this is the issue "Basically its the dependencies Ruby is compiled against; using rvm notes" from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438364/uninitialized-constant-cucumberrailsdatabase-nameerror-cucumber-mongoid ; I will try to run this project on another machine which using rbenv instead of rvm.

Comment: Hi Dave, I run this project on another machine which is using "rbenv", and the error still occurs; i.e "uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rails::Database::Strategy::DatabaseCleaner (NameError)"

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on from a series of comments. Think of what you can add to your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dave for helping me during the time. Briefly, in order for running "cucumber" without triggering to open a web-browser (which is rack-test), here is the configuration:

1> File env.rb.

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
```

Only 1 line above is enough.

2> File .feature

Feature: Post a new Product

```
Feature: Post a new Product
Scenario: Open new product page
Given I open new product site
When I input new product
Then I should see the product created confirmed
```

By the way, we don't need "Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium" within file env.rb.

There's still so many tricky things I need to learn about capybara and cucumber